# Why doesn't a VNC server provide multiple screen capability?

Tags: java, x11, xlib, vnc

I have a single Java application that can take advantage of more than one physical monitor described by a Linux X server as separate screens or one logical frame buffer (i.e. TwinView or Xinerama), but the same presentation of hardware isn't available in any VNC server implementation AFAIK.  I really want to understand what is the limiting factor(s) in VNC or RFB that prevents logical screens from being represented like a physical X server that has more than one display.

Possibly I have overlooked something out there that does this?

I understand that if I was writing C/C++ code I could take advantage of Xlib API and connect to multiple VNC server instances, but I'm stuck with Java's limitation of only connecting to a single X server per JVM as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840402/java-jframe-launch-another-jframe-to-another-x-server) per lack of response.

I also understand that I could instantiate a single VNC server with the width of the frame buffer of multiple displays.  This approach requires the code to change the location of what would be adjacent frames/windows and would differ from rendering on physical hardware.

What would be ideal is if you could start a VNC server like the following:

Xvnc :1 -geometry 1920x1080 -geometry 1920x1080

The result would be a frame buffer of 3840x1080, but when Java code such as the below would return more than a single GraphicsDevice:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
for(int i = 0; i < gd.length; i++){
    System.out.println(gd[i]);
}
```

The vncviewer shouldn't need to care about the logical screen(s), it would only need to represent the extended frame buffer as 3840x1080.

Comment: I did find that TigerVNC 1.9.0 with CentOS 8.0 has a feature to define screens and Java seems to pick up the configuration.  Here is an example:  Xvnc :1 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 -screen 1 1920x1080x24 +xinerama

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's limitation of the protocol (I have implemented low level client - https://github.com/sidorares/node-rfb2). One vnc connection represent one framebuffer rectangle (possibly changing it's width/height over time). You can build something on top of that, where server listens on separate port for each physical screen and client making 2 connections